# are the variables declared in programming language **terminal** symbols or **non-terminal** symbols

Tags: automata-theory, language-theory

I have a question in computation theory and automata .
are the variables declared in  programming language **terminal** symbols or **non-terminal** symbols .

Comment: Variables? Neither. But the *names* of variables may be either terminal or non-terminal, depending on how the grammar is presented.

Answer (score 0):

According to theory of automata, Variables in programming are nonterminals i.e. a finite
set of other symbols, each of which
represents a language.
Nonterminal symbols (or syntactic variables) are replaced by groups of terminal symbols according to the production rules.
In programming, variables are considered to be non-terminals because, variables represents data but not the variables themselves are  data. They are just representing the data with names known as non-terminals in automata theory.
Since, the variables in programming are obeying the properties of non-terminals in automata theory, variables are said to be non-terminals in programming because the compilers of the programming languages are designed by using automata.

*Variables in programming are non-terminals*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).